# What does qsub --cwd `pwd` mean?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am newbie to Linux command lines. I just got a queue submission command from others. The command line is as follows:

```
qsub --cwd `pwd` -t 60 -n 1 --proccount 1 --mode c1 --env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${FOAM_LIBBIN}:${FOAM_LIBBIN}/dummy:WM_PROJECT_DIR=${WM_PROJECT_DIR} ${FOAM_APPBIN}/blockMesh
```

I didn't quite understand the `` --cwd `pwd` `` part. 
I know the following parameters are related to time, nodes, processors and executable file. 
Can anyone help explain what `` --cwd `pwd` `` means?

Comment: what does `man qsub` say?

Comment: --cmd 'pwd' is for running the command  pwd (present working directory) and the qsub itself as a command  is a script configuration / run at    tool

Answer (score 3):

It's probably telling `qsub` to execute the command in the current working directory.

`pwd` is the shell command "print working directory", which just reports what your current working directory is. Putting that command in `backticks` tells the shell to execute that command in a sub-shell and insert its output into the command line in that place. So if you were currently in `/home/jerry` when you typed in the `qsub` command line, the command line would become `qsub --cwd /home/jerry`.

In some versions of `qsub`, there's a `-cwd` option that doesn't take an argument, and just always tells `qsub` to execute the command in the current working directory. It looks like your version of `qsub` has a `--cwd` option that can take an argument, and perhaps uses that argument as the path to "`cd` into" (i.e. set as its working directory) before executing the command. Or maybe your system's `qsub` doesn't really work that way, but whoever gave you that command mistakenly thought it worked that way.